# Writing data to excel from a formula in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

What I want is with openpyxl to write a value I get form a len() or dups() to an excel cell.
Here are my imports:

```
import xlwings as xw
```

Here is the code:

```
#Load workbook
app = xw.App(visible = False)
wb = xw.Book(FilePath)
RawData_ws = wb.sheets['Raw Data']
Sheet1 = wb.sheets['Sheet 1']

RawData_ws['A1'] = (len(df.index))
Sheet1['B7'] = (len(df.index) - tot_dups))
RawData_ws['A2'] = (len(df.index)) #This one is after removing duplicate values
```

Tot_dups:

```
tot_dups = len(df.index)
```

I want the values of the different len() to show be written in the specific cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I already found the solution.

Change:

```
RawData_ws['A1'] = (len(df.index))
```

For:

```
RawData_ws['A1'].values = (len(df.index))
```